# Configure angular webpack bundle to put css to bottom and combine js files to 1 file

Tags: javascript, angular, pageload

Load time of my angular project is too high somewhat around 7-8 seconds.

This is after implementing things like lazy loading modules, lazy loading css but still this time is too much.

Now i would like to combine all js files to 1 file to reduce requests and i want bundle to put css file at bottom of index.html so that it will not block render of the page.

Can anyone please help how to do that. (I am using angular universal)

Comment: I think when you go with lazy loading, js files can't be combined to one file.

Comment: you did a --prod build?

Comment: There should be another option to speed up your application. Check if AOT is used, it seems like it is not used

Comment: As @Andrei said use flag `--no-aot` along with `--prod` flag,  you will see a noticeable change in the build time.

Comment: `Now i would like to combine all js files to 1 file to reduce requests` that *reduces* nothing. Makes one bigger request but the bandwidth remains the same, but now you've lost all benefits of bundles.

Comment: `at bottom of index.html so that it will not block render` but this is already how Angular compiles the `index.html` file. The tags are always place at the bottom.

Comment: @cgTag i somehow agree with you about the js part but i have tested by putting css file at bottom of the page manually and it reduced my load time by half second. So if you can help how can we put it in bottom.

Comment: @CodingFreak Not familier about `aot` will definitely try it. It would be great if you can help with the same.

Comment: @enno.void yes i am doing --prod